# Parse an SQL record to select varying number of fields?

Tags: sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and I have a database that contains records. I want to run a query on those records and produce individual rows based on the parsing of the record - however if the unparsed string is contains a 01 I need to produce I row and if it contains 02 I need to produce 2 rows.

The data is like this:

```
01AAAA
01BBBB
02CCCCDDDD
02CCCCAAAA
01BBBB
02BBBBDDDD
01AAAA
```

and I want the following after my select statements:

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
DDDD
CCCC
AAAA
BBBB
BBBB
DDDD
AAAA
```

Is this possible using select and some kind of IF statements, or do I need to split the data into another table. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data you presented is actually representative of your actual data (2 characters followed by N number of 4 character values), then it's not going to be necessary to look at the 1st two characters.

See the following...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    ColumnToSplit VARCHAR(100)
    );

INSERT #TestData (ColumnToSplit) VALUES 
    ('01AAAA'),
    ('01BBBB'),
    ('02CCCCDDDD'),
    ('02CCCCAAAA'),
    ('01BBBB'),
    ('02BBBBDDDD'),
    ('01AAAA');


--=========================================

SELECT 
    sv.SplitValues
FROM
    #TestData td
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES 
                        (SUBSTRING(td.ColumnToSplit, 3, 4)),
                        (SUBSTRING(td.ColumnToSplit, 7, 4))
                    ) sv (SplitValues)
WHERE 
    sv.SplitValues <> '';
```

HTH,
Jason

Comment: Glad to help. :)